# Is it possible to get commits that has modified files that contains X?

Tags: git

I am curious; is it possible to get a list of commits, that has modified files where the file contents contains X (even though the commit has not pickaxed X)?

For example, let's say I have 100 files in a repository, 50 of these 100 files contains the word "hello" and the repository has 100 commits. Is it possible to get all commits that has modified any file that contains "hello"?

Maybe it is a brutal question to ask Git, if so, what easy performance tricks could I do to get such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you need, you can use:

```
git grep pattern $(git rev-list --all)
```

Or

```
git grep pattern $(git rev-list --all) | cut -d : -f 1
```

If you're interesting only in commits hashes.

Comment: For anyone wondering what the heck $(...) is, it is a shell command for substitution, so for this example it looks through all the revisions. For my particular case this is not needed though, as I just wanted the latest version of the file. But good info though.